# Is there a way to change a variable name while a for loop continues

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

Using python, trying to make a card game. I have images saved on my computer with the same name as the cards e.g. AH is Ace of hearts and saved on my computer as AH.png. This code does not work because as each iteration continues the image it makes replaces the last one as there variable name for the button in Tkinter is the same? So the only image that displays is the final one. Any way to fix this?

```
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()

cards = ['AH', 'KH', 'QH', 'JH', '10H', '9H', '8H']
# function to turn the list of cards to images

number = 0
for bit in cards:
    print(bit)
    Photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file=str(bit) + '.png')
    cardButton = tkinter.Button(window, image=Photo)
    cardButton.grid(row=5, column=number)
    number = number + 1

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You want a dict: `Photos[bit] = tkinter.PhotoImage(file=bit+'.png')`

Comment: I am pretty new, could you please explain a bit more

Comment: The photo part works fine, I don't mine removing the photo. What does not work is the cardButton var, as it gets replaces and when you place it again, it removes it from the last place!

Comment: standard rule: if you have many elements then keep them on list or dictionary. So before loop dictionary `photo = dict()` and inside loop put image in dictionary `photo[bit] = tkinter.PhotoImage(file=bit+'.png')`

Answer (score 2):

Rather than create different variables, store all the `Button` objects in a `dict` that maps a card "name" to its button.

```
window = tkinter.Tk()

cards = ['AH', 'KH', 'QH', 'JH', '10H', '9H', '8H']
# function to turn the list of cards to images

card_buttons = {}
for number, bit in enumerate(cards):
    photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file=bit + '.png')
    card_buttons[bit] = tkinter.Button(window, image=photo)
    card_buttons[bit].grid(row=5, column=number)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Still not working, only last image coming up : ( even when using your code

Comment: Are you sure `AH.png`, `KH.png`, etc are all actually different images? I may have misunderstood the question; if you don't need access to the individual objects, you don't need a `dict`. The code itself seems fine; I suspect the problem is with the images themselves.

Comment: They are definitely all separate images and I know they work because the final image, in this case, the 8 of hearts is displayed and the rest have space which have been made ie the window is elongated horizontally so you can see at some point there were there

Comment: That doesn't sound like something that has anything to do with the code you've shown.